# add a collection view controller to another controller as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to add a `collectionViewController` to another controller as subview.

`datasource` and `delegate` methods are called.

I can interact with the cells i.e, I can call `didSelectItemAtIndexpath`, but i can't see anything.

Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

```
 HairTypeFilterController *htfvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hairTypeFilterSBID"];

[self addChildViewController:htfvc];

[htfvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

htfvc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, _filterDetailsOutlet.frame.size.width, _filterDetailsOutlet.frame.size.height);
[_filterDetailsOutlet addSubview:htfvc.collectionView];
```

Comment: where is your implementation of collection view datasource method? it is only adding as subview code. "didSelectItemAtIndexpath" is a delegate method not need to call

Comment: // Register cell classes
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];   I had to remove this which comes by default. It is working now.

Comment: You can view ContainerView for that. It is easy to add Whole viewController as subview

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by removing the below single line of code which was by default implemented inside `uicollectionviewcontrollerclass`. Now its working.

```
// Register cell classes 
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```